# repeat the same div n time in vue js

Tags: vue.js

Hi there I'm trying to repeat a div n times,

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in details" :key="index">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <img  src='./img' width="250" alt class="imageLOGO"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=col-md-12>
                <div class="form-group" style="display:flex; justify-content:center;">
                    <div >
                        <h1>TEST</h1>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                        <p>{{this.$t(reports.title)}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

this is my data

```
data(){
    return{
       details: null
    }
```

Details is filled with an array that contains objects,

I want to iterate in this array so I can show n times the component.

And is showing me this error, in others components this error message doesn't show

Cannot read property '$t' of undefined"

Thanks

Comment: Do not use `this` in templates - everything in the template is automatically referenced from `this` (component instance)

Comment: remove "this" from this.$t, you don't need that in the template. So just: {{ $t(reports.title) }}

Comment: Yes guys it worked, thanks a lot for ur contribution. <3 <3